# Bigquery : Dateadd and datediff

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-date-functions

I am bit stuck at the below: 
    I am able to get the subpart of date_diff but not together.
    any help is appreciated.

```
SQL Server :
SELECT (DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 

Big Query : 
SELECT DATETIME_ADD(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, DATE '1900-01-01', DAY))
```

Comment: What's the goal? What's some sample input data, and the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SQL as an example

```
#standardSQL
        SELECT DATE_DIFF(DATE(CURRENT_DATETIME()), DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_DATETIME()) ,INTERVAL 3 DAY), DAY),INTERVAL 3 DAY), DAY)
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: @Aced assuming my answer helped you appreciate if you can accept it as the solution. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) to understand why this is important

Answer (score 0):

Without a clear understanding of the use case, I'm going just to correct the query:

1. You should specify time part when using some of the [DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_add) or [DATETIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_add) functions. In this case, you need to specify `DAY` for `DATETIME_ADD` function.
2. You can use `DATE_ADD` function if you do not need time.

So, this query is working as expected:

```
#standardSQL   
SELECT DATETIME_ADD(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, DATE '1900-01-01', DAY) DAY) as result_datetime,
       DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, DATE '1900-01-01', DAY) DAY) as result_date
```